# How to count elements in a list of lists of strings

Tags: python

If a have a list like this:

```
[['welcome','a1'],['welcome','a1'],['hello','a2'],['hello','a3']]
```

and I want to return something like this:

`[['welcome','a1', 2],['hello','a2', 1],['hello','a3', 1]]`

If the same pair of strings in a sublist is encountered, increment the count

What I have so far:

```
counter = 0
for i in mylist:
  counter += 1 
  if i[0]== i[0]:
    if i[1] == i[1]:
        counter -= 1
 ouptut.append([mylist, counter])
```

I'm new at this and I appreciate your help!

Comment: It sounds like a dictionary problem but the question is kinda poorly stated...

Comment: How did `'hello'` became `'hi'`?

Comment: Shouldn't the output of the example be `[['welcome', 'a1', 2], ['hello', 'a3', 1], ['hello', 'a2', 1]]`?

Comment: sorry I edited the question, I need to avoid the repetitions by comparing the 1st elem of each sublist and if it is alike compare the 2nd element (code) to chk the difference, if so count them separately otherwise just count it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `set` here to get only unique items:

```
>>> lis = [['welcome','a1'],['welcome','a1'],['hello','a2'],['hello','a3']] 
>>> [list(x) + [1] for x in set(map(tuple, lis))]
>>> [['welcome', 'a1', 1], ['hello', 'a3', 1], ['hello', 'a2', 1]]
```

**Explanation:**

Set always returns unique items from an iterable or iterator, but as sets can only contain immutable item so you should convert them to a tuple first. A verbose version of the above code, only difference is that will also preserve the original or

```
>>> lis = [['welcome','a1'],['welcome','a1'],['hello','a2'],['hello','a3']] 
>>> s = set()
>>> for item in lis:
...     tup = tuple(item)  #covert to tuple
...     s.add(tup)
>>> s
set([('welcome', 'a1'), ('hello', 'a3'), ('hello', 'a2')])
```

Now use a list comprehension to get the expected output:

```
>>> [list(item) + [1] for item in s]
[['welcome', 'a1', 1], ['hello', 'a3', 1], ['hello', 'a2', 1]]
```

If the order of items matter(`sets` don't preserve order), then use this:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> ans = []
>>> for item in lis:
...     tup = tuple(item)
...     if tup not in seen:
...         ans.append(item + [1])
...         seen.add(tup)
...         
>>> ans
[['welcome', 'a1', 1], ['hello', 'a2', 1], ['hello', 'a3', 1]]
```

I am not sure what's the point of using `1` here.

Comment: I was *just* about to edit my answer to include this exact thing, +1

Comment: It seems that it work but I don't understand fully your code to do it... but thanks

Comment: How you can edit the loop so as to get [['hello', 'a1',1], ['hello', 'a1',1]]; return ['hello', 'a1',2],... This is just to understand the logic better. Thank you for your replies! :)

Comment: @JPP Have a look at [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

Comment: Should I change if tup not in seen: to => if tup in seen: ??

Comment: @JPP No, that won't do it. You need to keep a count of each item, dicts are good for this thing, specially `collections.Counter`. Convert the inner item to tuples before passing them to `Counter`.

Comment: Hi again! I checked the collections.counter out but I don't find exactly the counter for my list. You were right I need to count [['hello', 'a1',1], ['hello', 'a1',1], ['welcome', 'b1',1]]; return [['hello', 'a1',2],['welcome', 'b1',1]]. The loop that you posted was [list(item) + [v] for (a,b),v item in s]?

Comment: cuz I have this:  def compara(lista):
    listaPalabras=[]
    res = []
    result = []
    cont = 0
    for item in lista:
        if item[2] in eagles_dict.keys():
            listaPalabras.append([item[1],item[2]])
            for i in listaPalabras:
                cont = cont + 1
                listaPalabras.append(cont)